# Pass array setFlashdata in redirect codeigniter4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4

i have code pass data from login to dashboard view like this..

```
$session = \Config\Services::session();
$data = [
                'id_user'=>$cek['id_user'],
                'name' => $cek['name'],
                'no_hp' => $cek['no_hp'],
                'type_user' => $cek['type_user'],
                'image' => $cek['image'],
                'email' => $cek['email'],
              ];
            $session->setFlashdata('data', $data);
            return redirect()->to(base_url('/owner/dashboard'.$data));
```

i try to pass it in view but notworking

how to use $session->getFlashdata() correctly?

i want populate it like

```
Your name is :<?= $_SESSION['name'] ?>
Number is :<?= $_SESSION['no_hp] ?>
```

but still cant understand when read at
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#flashdata

thanks for answer my problem,...

Comment: according from docs, because you store flashdata session "data" with array $data, try access your session data like <?= $_SESSION['data']['name'] ?>

Comment: @LexaVey is correct, you are not accessing that value correctly. You are adding that entire array as Session data, not its individual contents.